# Is it possible to set up a GitLab Linux server and work off Windows PCs?

Tags: linux, windows, git, gitlab

I'm looking at setting up a gitlab server (using a linux machine) with several devs on Windows PCs using it. I basically wanted to know if that's possible? I can't seem to find a definitive answer!

Thanks!

Comment: However, teaching your students to use Linux is also worthwhile (especially for programming tasks). So installing Linux on the classroom PCs could make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. I'm using just the same - GitLab hosted on a Linux server while devs are on both Windows and Linux (VMs running on Windows).

Techically, there's no difference to it. You use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH) and [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for client-server communication which are standard platform independent protocols. It's the same as using [github.com](http://github.com), [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com) or any other such provider from any operating system.

Comment: Would you clarify on what you mean by 'the same'? Do you mean you're working on Windows using a GitLab server or working on Linux? Thanks!

Comment: @LazyTotoro Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

The place I work has Gitlabs deployed can be on a linux server, while developers can be on either Windows or Linux desktops.

Git makes use of SSH and to connect to remote clients and Windows doesn't support SSH out of the box, however the installer for git comes bundled with all the features you will need to run a shell and connect to a remote server via SSH on windows.  It also includes a basic UI, Git-Gui.  You can download the installer from http://git-scm.com.